# How do I hang a shelf without drilling holes?

Tags: walls, mounting, asbestos

I'm currently living in a house in which we have clear instructions not to drill through the walls for danger of asbestos.

I purchased a small projector and would like to mount a shelf to the wall, but I know that I cannot drill through. The projector weighs about 1lbs, and the shelf could be just a piece of wood or plastic stuck to the wall. Does anyone have any suggestions about making this shelf and how to stick it to the wall without drilling through?

Comment: *weighs almost nothing* as in how much? Also, your best bet may be a floor standing bookshelf or something similar.

Comment: probably like 1 pound, if that...Yeah I was thinking that, but I wanted to mount it above my couch facing the other way, so ideally the couch could be up against the wall too...Thanks!

Comment: If the ceiling doesn't have asbestos (which seems unlikely), then you could anchor it to the ceiling. I can't think of any way to mount a cantilever shelf to the wall without piercing it with screws or nails unless you used strong glue or tape (which may damage the wall and release asbestos when removed). Maybe a wooden brace that goes from floor to ceiling with some kind of spring loaded anchor to hold it in place against the ceiling? Here's an example of an entire [spring loaded shelf system](http://www.instructables.com/id/Stolmen-and-Ekby-compression-bookshelf-system/)

Comment: Anything that uses stickers or glue could rip the wall right open when it falls.  Far worse than a couple screw holes.

Comment: If the walls have asbestos, the ceiling might also - ie, if they are plastered, the plaster is probably the same.

Comment: Since you don't actually mind living in a house with asbestos in the walls, what's a little drilling.

Answer (score 4):

A "**C**" (or perhaps "**[**" is better) shaped shelf could sit under and behind the couch, keeping it no more than an inch or two (even less if it was metal plate for the section behind the top edge of the couch) off the wall, and holding the projector above the couch without needing any attachment into the walls.

Not exactly what I'm thinking of (not having much luck thinking of the right search terms to find what I am thinking of), but the general idea - legs that can slip under the couch, standards, a shelf.

[image: Shelf]

Answer (score 4):

How about instead of mounting it to the wall, use a couple vertical tension rods from floor to ceiling and connect shelves to those? See this IKEA hack:

http://lifehacker.com/5890036/mount-your-hdtv-on-a-set-of-floor+to+ceiling-poles-keep-your-wall-hole+free

Oh, actually I see Johnny answered with a similar post. But while the link he gave works, the links at the site he gave (which detail the parts used) don't seem to be working for me.

Anyway, a quick look at IKEA's web site should give you some parts to use. Like these:

Stolmen post: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20179940/
Stolmen shelf: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/70179947/
Stolmen end fixture: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/50179934/

If it's just a small component like you mentioned, you might even make do with just one tension pole. No need for a shelf! To mount your device to the pole, you can do a number of things. First, you can buy one of those "O" rings and mount a small, lightweight shelf to it - maybe a thin piece of backer board or plastic from a clipboard or something. You just have to drill a hole into the shelf and attach it with a screw, two washers, and a nut. And then put your device on top of that.

But that may not be a perfect solution if the "O" ring can't handle the force or the shelf sags at a downward angle over time. Instead, you might want to just make your own custom plastic frame to hold your device. It's super easy. Just buy some some Insta Morph and shape it into whatever you want.

Insta Morph melts at 150 degrees F, and then you can shape it for a few minutes until it solidifies. It takes about an hour for it to become completely solid, and when it's like that, it's indistinguishable from any other hard plastic you've seen. Just have to watch the heat from the device, make sure it doesn't re-melt the plastic (it can be melted again and reused any number of times by the way)...

[http://www.amazon.com/InstaMorph-Moldable-Plastic-12-oz/dp/B003QKLJKQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003QKLJKQ)

Oh and by the way, the idea of using vertical tension rods to make shelving is genius. It's easy to put together and take down. It's very customizable, allowing any shelf width and depth you want. It can be added onto later on if you want. And in my opinion, it looks very nice, clean and modern. You may not need the shelving for your purposes, but it doesn't hurt to have extra shelving!

Comment: +1 Interesting answer to interesting question! You may consider adding horizontal tension rods (if circumstances are okay: e. g. between some high shelves) to the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the stands that will rest on ground and support your shelves. Or use some chain or rope and screw some hook on your shelves to hang it using or rope.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done this a lot over the years at my place, as I had a family member that used to work for Velcro, full disclosure.

Either Velcro, or 3M, even other brands have these [strips you can use to hang pictures](https://amzn.to/2Hq0sFe), shelves, coat hangers (as I have) that are great, and best of all, they are removable without messing up the paint.

**This will only work for a shelf if you have some gussets underneath**, if its just a free standing shelf it will fail immediately or eventually anyway.

I have also used [double sided tape](https://amzn.to/2F2eHNN), which is extremely strong, but removed the paint from the wall once I had to remove what I had hanging.
I did use this for a coat hanger in the back of a door, and there I had no issues.

[image: Hang picture frames and shelves without holes or removing paint]

**[Link at Amazon](https://amzn.to/2Hq0sFe)**